# How can I make create a circle with blurry shadow

Tags: css

I want to create a circle with a blurry shadow

[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUvW1.png)

Comment: You mean [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [filter: blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur).

```css
.blurryCircle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(25px);
 }
```

```html
<span class="blurryCircle">&nbsp;</span>
```

Alternatively, if you want a solid circle, *with* a blurry shadow, you could use [filter: drop-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow).

```css
.blurryCircle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 25px blue);
 }
```

```html
<span class="blurryCircle">&nbsp;</span>
```